# Is there an Alternative to org.slf4j.Logger.addAppender()

Tags: java, unit-testing, junit, slf4j, slf4j-api

I'm updating an old project to use the latest version of the following dependencies:

```
compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-core:1.4.4'
compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-classic:1.4.4'
compile 'ch.qos.logback:logback-access:1.4.4'
compile 'org.slf4j:slf4j-api:2.0.3'
```

In the older version of the above dependencies (i.e. `1.2.x`) the following piece of code in my test class used to work:

```
logger.addAppender(listAppender);
```

However, because `addAppender()` is no longer supported in the new versions, this test fails.

**My question** is that is there a different approach that equates to using `addAppender` to get coverage for my loggers?